# Advanced lookup formulas based on a combination of unique rules

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating an attendance tracking form for work and require someone with more advanced knowledge of excel. This is to track employee tardy's and unplanned absences (UPT). When employees get too many tardy's or UPT's it is called an "Occurrence", when the number of occurrences increase it will increase the "Action Level". I input new data every 2 weeks and then send out emails to notify employees and their managers of increased action levels due to these attendance issues, I want this spreadsheet to do some of the work for me since I am working with hundreds of employees and so the process can sometimes take multiple days to complete.

My objective is to populate the Employee overview cells with the correct details from the Attendance Details page. The challenging part is that there are three rules that dictate which dates I need to populate the Employee Overview with.

Rule 1: Four tardies (TAR) makes an occurrence.

Rule 2: One UPT makes an occurrence, but if there can be multiple UPT's that only make one occurrence as long as they are within 5 days of each other.

Rule 3: Tardies and UPT's disappear after 365 days.

The increase of occurrences will increase the action level (See table in Employee Overview Screenshot).

In my example screenshots, the details should produce the hardcoded Employee overview I made for Bob Smith. I am not expecting anyone to have all the answers, but please help me by suggesting tips or tools available for accomplishing what I require. Please ask any clarifying questions if you wish to help but don't understand what I am requiring.

[Screenshot of Attendance Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E46EP.png)

[Screenshot of Employee Overview for Bob Smith (Hardcoded)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxWbl.png)

Comment: Look for similar questions already asked, here are links to two : https://stackoverflow.com/q/51294733/4961700 and  https://stackoverflow.com/q/51136593/4961700

Comment: Your data shared is great. I see this as a properly asked questions in excel. It just missed one thing, so what is the code/syntax/equation you had tried? Mind to share? it'll surely helps others to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose :

1. break the task/evaluation
2. Each rule may generate a set of new cell/data/table. thus, work with 1 rule first.
3. Repeat for another rule.
4. Consolidate.

these are just my head thinking out loud... hope it helps in anyways.. (care to comment? :)

Rule 1 : `=if(countif(<TarRange>,"TAR")>=4,1,0)` OR `=countif(<TarRange>,"TAR")/4`

Rule 2 : make a new list of "UPT"& its date, work from there. arranged the data by date, and use `=if((day(<NextEntryDate>-day(<previousEntryDate>))<=5,<currentEntrydate>,"")`

Rule 3 : every date cell values can be extracted using year(),month() and day(). Also look in to days calculation in excel help. I see that you'll need an extra column (beside the Rule 2 list) to do a moving summation. An example of moving summation is in the column H & I inside this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294733/calculating-excel-formula-for-total-time-within-a-sign-in-database/51467732#51467732) :

---

it uses `if(<Day1>=<Day2>,<Count>,<DontCount>)` Syntax. it can be change to year1/year2 in your case.

IMHO. Do share with us if you are stuck/successful. (:

Comment: This has been very helpful. I am going to be playing with these ideas as soon as I have time to fix my spreadsheet. Thank you for the detailed response!